# Should I override AlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have function which creates dialog

```
fun abs(){
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
//and so on
}
```

And I want to use `setOnCancelListener`

```
builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
builder.setOnCancelListener(DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
someFunction(view)
})
```

The main problem is that `someFunction(view)` must be used before builder/dialog is cancelled.
How can I achieve that? Do I need to override some function of `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private fun showAlertDialog(){
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("title")
        .setMessage("message")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .create()

    dialog.setOnShowListener(object: DialogInterface.OnShowListener{
        override fun onShow(p0: DialogInterface?) {
            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener{
                someFunction()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    })
}
```